# How do i solve this error of unmet dependencies?

Tags: linux, installation, dependencies, ros

I get the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-hydro-desktop : Depends: ros-hydro-ros-full but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: ros-hydro-visualization-tutorials but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: ros-hydro-viz but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: You should ask this on [ROS Answers](http://answers.ros.org), as that is the official ROS support forum. See the [ROS Support](http://wiki.ros.org/Support) page for more information.

Comment: You'll probably get better help by following Eric's advice, but you should also try to include some more details about the events leading up to this error. What exact command did you run? Have you tried anything to fix the issue already?